# Creating a contact form for a WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a contact form for my WordPress theme so that even unregistered users can message me.

I have installed my template on localhost to make sure my contact form codes work without any problem.

The problem I'm having is that when I click the submit button, instead of showing a successful submission message or any other error, it immediately jumps to the post page and no email is sent.

The code I put in the `functions.php` file:

```
function display_contact_form() {

    $validation_messages = [];
    $success_message = '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['contact_form'] ) ) {

        //Sanitize the data
        $full_name = isset( $_POST['full_name'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['full_name'] ) : '';
    $email     = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] ) : '';
    $subject   = isset( $_POST['subject'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['subject'] ) : '';
    $message   = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['message'] ) : '';

        //Validate the data
        if ( strlen( $full_name ) === 0 ) {
      $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid name.', 'twentytwentyone' );
    }
    
    if ( strlen( $email ) === 0 or
      ! is_email( $email ) ) {
      $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid email address.', 'twentytwentyone' );
    }
    
    if ( strlen( $subject ) === 0 ) {
      $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid subject.', 'twentytwentyone' );
    }
    
    if ( strlen( $message ) === 0 ) {
      $validation_messages[] = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid message.', 'twentytwentyone' );
    }

        //Send an email to the WordPress administrator if there are no validation errors
        if ( empty( $validation_messages ) ) {

            $mail    = get_option( 'admin_email' );
            $subject = 'New message from ' . $full_name;
            $message = $message . ' - The email address of the customer is: ' . $mail;

            wp_mail( $mail, $subject, $message );

            $success_message = esc_html__( 'Your message has been successfully sent.', 'twentytwentyone' );

        }

    }

    //Display the validation errors
    if ( ! empty( $validation_messages ) ) {
        foreach ( $validation_messages as $validation_message ) {
            echo '<div class="validation-message">' . esc_html( $validation_message ) . '</div>';
        }
    }

    //Display the success message
    if ( strlen( $success_message ) > 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="success-message">' . esc_html( $success_message ) . '</div>';
    }

    ?>

    <!-- Echo a container used that will be used for the JavaScript validation -->
    <div id="validation-messages-container"></div>


    <section id="bodyMainFormEmail">

<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"
method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="contact_form">

<div class="form-section">
    <label class="label_form-email" for="full-name"><?php echo esc_html( 'Full Name', 'twentytwentyone' ); ?></label>
    <input class="all_input-email" type="text" id="full-name" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
</div>

<div class="form-section">
    <label class="label_form-email" for="email"><?php echo esc_html( 'Email', 'twentytwentyone' ); ?></label>
    <input class="all_input-email input-email" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>

<div class="form-section">
    <label class="label_form-email" for="subject"><?php echo esc_html( 'Subject', 'twentytwentyone' ); ?></label>
    <input class="all_input-email" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
</div>

<div class="form-section">
    <label class="label_form-email" for="message"><?php echo esc_html( 'Message', 'twentytwentyone' ); ?></label>
    <textarea class="all_input-email message_email" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</div>

<input class="input_submit-email" type="submit" id="contact-form-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( 'submit', 'twentytwentyone' ); ?>">

</form>

</section>

    <?php

}
```

---

**Edit:**

Contact form script:

```
const contactFormSubmit = document.getElementById('contact-form-submit');
contactFormSubmit.addEventListener('click', validateForm);

function validateForm(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  //Full name
  const fullName = document.getElementById('full-name') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('full-name').value :
      '';

  //Email
  const email = document.getElementById('email') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('email').value :
      '';

  //subject
  const subject = document.getElementById('subject') !== null ?
  document.getElementById('subject').value :
  '';

  //Message
  const message = document.getElementById('message') !== null ?
      document.getElementById('message').value :
      '';

  const validationMessages = [];
  if (fullName.length === 0) {
    validationMessages.push('Please enter a valid name.');
  }

  if (email.length === 0 || !emailIsValid(email)) {
    validationMessages.push('Please enter a valid email address.');
  }

  if (subject.length === 0) {
    validationMessages.push('Please enter a valid subject.');
  }

  if (message.length === 0) {
    validationMessages.push('Please enter a valid message.');
  }

  if (validationMessages.length === 0) {

    //Submit the form
    document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();

  } else {

    //Delete all the existing validation messages from the DOM
    const parent = document.getElementById('validation-messages-container');
    while (parent.firstChild) {
      parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
    }

    //Add the new validation messages to the DOM
    validationMessages.forEach(function(validationMessage, index) {

      //add message to the DOM
      const divElement = document.createElement('div');
      divElement.classList.add('validation-message');
      const node = document.createTextNode(validationMessage);
      divElement.appendChild(node);

      const element = document.getElementById('validation-messages-container');
      element.appendChild(divElement);

    });

  }

}

/**
 * A simple function that verify the email with a regular expression.
 *
 * @param email
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function emailIsValid(email) {

  const regex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
  return regex.test(email);

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you provided seems to be missing the necessary hook to display the contact form. In WordPress, you typically use hooks to execute functions at specific points during the execution of a page.

To display the contact form, you need to hook the `display_contact_form()` function to a suitable WordPress action or filter. Here's an example of how you can modify the code to display the form correctly:

```
// Add this code to your functions.php file or your custom plugin

// Hook the display_contact_form() function to the 'the_content' filter
add_filter('the_content', 'display_contact_form');

function display_contact_form($content) {
    $validation_messages = [];
    $success_message = '';

    if (isset($_POST['contact_form'])) {
        // Your validation and email sending logic goes here
        // ...

        // After processing the form, you can set the success message
        $success_message = esc_html__('Your message has been successfully sent.', 'twentytwentyone');
    }

    // Build the contact form HTML
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <!-- Echo the HTML markup for the contact form -->
    <!-- ... Your contact form HTML code here ... -->
    <?php

    // Retrieve the contact form HTML from the output buffer
    $contact_form = ob_get_clean();

    // Append the success message to the contact form HTML
    if (strlen($success_message) > 0) {
        $contact_form .= '<div class="success-message">' . esc_html($success_message) . '</div>';
    }

    // Return the modified content
    return $contact_form . $content;
}
```

Comment: Hello. I put your code in the `function` file. The problem is still the same. By clicking the send button, I will be transferred to the `single page (post)` and no email will be sent. Meanwhile, I am testing on the local host and have installed the `Flamingo plugin` to display the sent emails.

Comment: The second problem is related to the display codes of the HTML form and its messages. Another contact form will be created along with the corresponding message on the `single page`.

Comment: If the issue persists even after implementing the suggested changes, there might be additional factors affecting the behavior of the contact form. Here are a few potential areas to investigate:

Comment: Check for JavaScript conflicts: Ensure that there are no JavaScript errors or conflicts on the page that might interfere with the form submission or redirection. You can check the browser console for any error messages.

Comment: Verify the form action URL: Double-check that the action attribute of the <form> element points to the correct URL for the form submission. In your code, it's currently set to action="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>". Make sure this URL corresponds to the correct page or endpoint that handles the form submission.

Comment: Test without plugins: Disable any additional plugins, including the Flamingo plugin, to eliminate the possibility of conflicts. Temporarily deactivate other plugins and see if the form submission works as expected.

Comment: Review server configurations: Ensure that your local development environment is set up correctly with a functioning mail server. Check your server configurations to confirm that emails can be sent from your local environment.

Comment: Hello. I did everything you said. When I transferred my site template from local host to my main host, a contact form was created on all pages of my site by pressing the submit button. I also used a script that I put in the edit of my question.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the PHP code. Do you have a better code so I can create a simple contact form for my template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254037/discussion-between-php-and-mohsin-mujawar).

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT